# Facing set datapath error while using tesseract in java

Tags: java, pdf, tesseract, pdfbox, tess4j

I am using tesseract to recognize text from pdfs and I am facing some weird error. 
The error is 
Error opening data file data/tessdata/eng.traineddata
Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to the parent directory of your "tessdata" directory.

Now, I understand the meaning of this error and my path is updated to the parent directory of data folder.
But the weird thing is that I don't get this error instantly when I run my code but I get it after recognizing 10-15 pdfs(consistiong of roughly 40 pages each).
After I get this error and run my program again from the pdf at which the program stopped before, then I get no errors for another 10-15 pdfs readings.

Now this is weird and I don't understand the reason behind this.
If someone have faced this or know reason behind this Please comment.

This is a function I use to recognize text from a particular page of my pdf. I call this function for each page of every pdf.

```
public static void getOCRDataFromPage(PDDocument pdDoc, int page, ArrayList<Characters> ch)
{
    TessBaseAPI handle=TessAPI1.TessBaseAPICreate();
    TessAPI1.TessBaseAPIInit3(handle, "data", "eng");
    try
    {
     double w=pdDoc.getPage(page-1).getCropBox().getWidth();
     double h=pdDoc.getPage(page-1).getCropBox().getHeight();

     PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(pdDoc);
     BufferedImage image = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(page-1, 300,ImageType.GRAY);
     //image=ImageHelper.convertImageToGrayscale(image);
     ImageIOUtil.writeImage(image,"G:/Trial/tempImg.png", 300);
     int bpp = image.getColorModel().getPixelSize();
     int bytespp = bpp / 8;
     int bytespl = (int) Math.ceil(image.getWidth() * bpp / 8.0);
     int height = image.getHeight();
     int width = image.getWidth();

     TessAPI1.TessBaseAPISetImage(handle, ImageIOHelper.convertImageData(image), width, height, bytespp, bytespl);
     TessAPI1.TessBaseAPISetPageSegMode(handle, TessPageSegMode.PSM_AUTO);
     image.flush();
     image=null;
     ETEXT_DESC monitor = new ETEXT_DESC();
     TessAPI1.TessBaseAPIRecognize(handle, monitor);
     TessResultIterator ri = TessAPI1.TessBaseAPIGetIterator(handle);
     TessPageIterator pi = TessAPI1.TessResultIteratorGetPageIterator(ri);
     TessAPI1.TessPageIteratorBegin(pi);
     int level = TessAPI1.TessPageIteratorLevel.RIL_WORD;
     ArrayList<Words> wd=new ArrayList<Words>();
     do {
     Pointer ptr = TessAPI1.TessResultIteratorGetUTF8Text(ri, level);
     if(ptr == null || ptr.toString().length()==0)
         break;
     String word = ptr.getString(0);
     TessAPI1.TessDeleteText(ptr);
     float confidence = TessAPI1.TessResultIteratorConfidence(ri, level);
     IntBuffer leftB = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
     IntBuffer topB = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
     IntBuffer rightB = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
     IntBuffer bottomB = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
     TessAPI1.TessPageIteratorBoundingBox(pi, level, leftB, topB, rightB, bottomB);
     int left = leftB.get();
     int top = topB.get();
     int right = rightB.get();
     int bottom = bottomB.get();
     IntBuffer boldB = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
     IntBuffer italicB = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
     IntBuffer underlinedB = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
     IntBuffer monospaceB = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
     IntBuffer serifB = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
     IntBuffer smallcapsB = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
     IntBuffer pointSizeB = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
     IntBuffer fontIdB = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
     String fontName = TessAPI1.TessResultIteratorWordFontAttributes(ri, boldB, italicB, underlinedB,
     monospaceB, serifB, smallcapsB, pointSizeB, fontIdB);
     boolean bold = boldB.get() == TRUE;
     boolean italic = italicB.get() == TRUE;
     boolean underlined = underlinedB.get() == TRUE;
     boolean monospace = monospaceB.get() == TRUE;
     boolean serif = serifB.get() == TRUE;
     boolean smallcaps = smallcapsB.get() == TRUE;
     int pointSize = pointSizeB.get();
     int fontId = fontIdB.get();
     Words chr=new Words(); // Words is a user-defined class 
     chr.c=word.concat(" ");
     chr.b=bold==true?1:0;
     chr.x=left*w/width;
     chr.size=pointSize;
     chr.name=fontName;
     chr.y=top*h/height;
     chr.w=(right-left)*w/width;
     chr.h=(bottom-top)*h/height;
     if(pointSize>1)
         wd.add(chr);
     } while (TessAPI1.TessPageIteratorNext(pi, level) == TRUE);

     sortWords(wd);
     wordsToChar(wd,ch);
     wd=null;
    }
catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
         //TessAPI1.TessBaseAPIClearAdaptiveClassifier(handle);
         TessAPI1.TessBaseAPIClearPersistentCache(handle);
         TessAPI1.TessBaseAPIClear(handle);
         //TessAPI1.TessBaseAPIDelete(handle);
         TessAPI1.TessBaseAPIEnd(handle);
         handle=null;
    }

}
```

If anyone spots anything out of the ordinary then do reply.

Comment: I won't be able to help with tesseract, but wanted to mention: 1) do not forget to check the return code of ImageIOUtil.writeImage(), 2) don't construct PDFRenderer for each image. Once per document is enough.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr, Will do all that.
 This was the code I was referring to in our scratch buffer discussion so do you find anything which could lead to that error?
It's fine If you can't help with tesseract.
Thanks!

Comment: no, can't find anything else. Btw the fine people at Apache TIKA have started to experiment with tesseract too. Don't know if it has been released or is still experimental. Maybe look in their own source code. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-1994